# Problemas de conectividad con Kali Linux

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux, nmap

Buen dia

Estoy teniendo problemas tratandi de dectar el ip de las maquinas encendias en la pc usando kali linux.
Tal y como me comentan tengo que usarlos en NAT, la primera maquina es kali linux, y la que trato de conectar es un os llamado metasplotable.
Entonces pongo `arp-scan -I eth0 {mi ip}/24` y solamente aparecen 3 ip, que terminan en 1, 2, 3. Despues de esto tengo que usar `nmap` con la ip que saque.

---

¿Algo que tengo que cambiar?
Gracias